# Json_dynamic_widget custom function is not working as i expected

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

right now im learning about json_dynamics_widget for my server driven ui project, i tried to make a custom function and called it in json. It work but not as i  expected. I want the function to work when i tap on a text, but the function get called when build/rebuild widget not when i tap text. Here is the full code
Dart Code:

```
void main() async {
  var registry = JsonWidgetRegistry.instance;

  registry.registerFunction('changeText', ({args, required registry}) {
      print("some text: ${args?[0]}");
    });
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String? gestureText = "belum terisi";

  changeText(String? text) {
    print("ke print: $text");
    gestureText = text;
  }


  Map widgetsData = {
    "type": "scaffold",
    "args":{
      "body":{
        "type": "center",
        "child": {
          "type": "circular_progress_indicator"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var registry = JsonWidgetRegistry.instance;
  
  Future<Map> readJson() async {
    final String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/widgets.json");
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    print("json: $json");
    return json;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registry.setValue('gestureText', gestureText);
    
    readJson().then((value) {
      setState(() {
       widgetsData = value;
       print("widgetValue = $widgetsData");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widget = JsonWidgetData.fromDynamic(widgetsData,registry: registry);
    return widget!.build(context: context);
  }
}
```

Json Code:

```
{
  "type": "scaffold",
  "args": {
    "appBar": {
      "type": "app_bar",
      "args": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "args": {
            "text": "Gestures"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "center",
      "child": {
        "type": "column",
        "args": {
          "mainAxisSize": "min"
        },
        "children": [{
          "type": "row",
          "args": {
            "mainAxisSize": "min"
          },
          "children": [{
            "type": "checkbox",
            "args": {
              "label": "Ignore Gestures",
              "value": false
            },
            "id": "ignore"
          }, {
            "type": "text",
            "args": {
              "text": "Ignore taps"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "type": "sized_box",
          "args": {
            "height": "16"
          }
        }, {
          "type": "ignore_pointer",
          "args": {
            "ignoring": "${ignore}"
          },
          "child": {
            "type": "gesture_detector",
            "args": {
              "onTap": "${changeText('text yang sangat panjang sekali')}"
            },
           
            "child": {
              "type": "padding",
              "args": {
                "padding": 20
              },
              "child": {
                "type": "text",
                "args": {
                  "text": "Tap Me!"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          "type": "sized_box",
          "args": {
            "height": "16"
          }
        }, {
          "type": "text",
          "args": {
            "text": "${gestureText}"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to called the function without using "&{}" is not work, i tried use registry.setValue, the result is still same